# How do I insert into a MySQL database using a loop for multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

I have data that will need to be added into a database. The data looks like this:

```
Jim Jones    2009-01-01     Red
Susan Hoo    2009-01-04     Red
...
```

I am writing a procedure for this but don't know how to loop it so that it inserts all of the rows. Is there a tutorial or something that someone can show me to get me started?

Thanks

This is a procedure that will insert live data, the data is not in a file.

Comment: IS the data from a form? Where do you get the data to input into the database?

Comment: The data starts from a form and then will be entered into the database using a procedure.

Comment: this is not a mysql question, it is a question about whatever programming language you are using to write the input gui

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what form you have the data in.  If you have it as text or CSV, you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  But I don't think that will work if you have it all in a single line (hard to tell from your example).

Otherwise if you need to do it programmatically, it would help a lot if you told us which language you were using.

**Edit** - much better with formatting.  Here is the reference page for `LOAD DATA INFILE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

**Edit 2** - in response to your comment, what is the interface through which users will insert new records?

**Edit 3** - ok, if you have a GUI through which they will insert a record then you don't need to have a for loop, since presumably only one record gets inserted at a time.  Ignoring the possibility of batching for the moment, you should just perform an `INSERT` whenever the user indicates through the GUI that they would like to submit their record.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified this above but these are inserts that will happen as people add info to the database. If a user chooses multiple selections, we want to save them.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like a beginner so here is a simple answer.  From within your development tool press F1 or select help from the menu and search for: "for", "while", "do", "until" or "loop". These are the common looping keywords.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm writing this by hand. Can you recommend a tool that can help?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at multi dimensional arrays - suppose you have your input stored in a multi dimensional array similar to this:

```
$myform = array(

 0 => array(

 "name" => "Jim Jones",

 "date" => "2009-01-01",

 "colour" => "red"

 ),

 1 => array(

 "name" => "Susan Hoo",

 "date" => "2009-01-04",

 "colour" => "red"

 )
```

you could then do something like this:

```
for($x=0;$x<(sizeof($data_array));$x++) {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO your_db_table (

name,

date,

colour

) VALUES (

'$myform[$x][name]',

'$myform[$x][date]',

'$myform[$x][colour]'

)"

)

}
```

..please handle with care! Although I use something similar in various applications, the above coding is not tested and has probably the one or the other bug. Hope it helps anyways..:]